# Flutter Custom List view like This

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC3qe.jpg)>How I make dynamic custom list view like this?

> Any component For this ?

Comment: what you have tried so far? Add your codes that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this sample example and the image.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SampleApp(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleAppState createState() => _SampleAppState();
}

class _SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your heading'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Card(
                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Name'),
                                Text('Date'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text('Your text'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                          Icon(Icons.camera_enhance),
                          Icon(Icons.camera_rear),
                          Icon(Icons.card_membership)
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Add text and icons as per you wish.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Yuh So muCH, And WHat Say this type of list?

Comment: This is the custom type of listview how so ever you want change the things and mould as per your needs.

Comment: Please make an upvote so that it would be helpful for others as well.